# CSS/HTML Table with different sized cells

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create a table with a number of different sized cells, but from what I know creating tables with html/css seems too ridged for something like this:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a link to the picture?

Comment: It would look a little something like this

Comment: http://www.cpp.edu/~jlkorey/POWERMUTT/Topics/contingency_tables_files/table9.gif

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is cell width. You can do this in HTML (the CSS is only to show the result):

```css
td {
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td width="500px">Cell 1</td><td width-"100px">Cell 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

You can change height too, but as far as I know you can only change height per row:

```css
td {
  background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td width="500px" height="100px">Cell 1</td><td width="100px">Cell 2</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition to the width and height of each , you can use the "colspan" and "rowspan" attributes as well. Like in the cell in your picture with the text: "Iraq war worth the cost", you can have something like the following:

```
<td rowspan="2">
```

See the following link for examples:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp